# What is the best way with dealing with internal links while scraping

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm building a web scraper in C# and getting all links on a page by doing the following:

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))

}
```

This is being ran on the Internet so the links could be malformed or even different protocols. What is the best way to convert internal links such as /gohere/index.html or potato.php to an external link which also contains the sites URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done pretty easily, you can construct a new Uri using the Uri you used to get the page.

Like this:

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com");
Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "catalog/shownew.htm");

Console.WriteLine(myUri.ToString());
```

For more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hst1w91.aspx

This works for relative and absolute href's alike, so there's no need to check, you just 'convert' every link you find on a page like that.

Comment: One question, what happens with externals links when found in the same page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm little confused here that "This is being ran on the Internet" part. Are you first downloading a web-page and then scraping it?
Also, if language is no dependency, I would recommend using jSoup. It will answer most of your queries.

Comment: I'm downloading and parsing all links on a page, some link are internal and some are external.

Answer (score 0):

Although [shriek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1260405/shriek) answer is right, I prefer the easy way:

```
List<string> links = new List<string>();
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
    links.Add("http://mywebsite.com"+link.InnerText);
}
```